# How can I isolate this variable inside a square root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble isolating the variable $x$ in this equation:
$$x^2\sqrt{3}+x(\sqrt{1-x^2}-1)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

$$x^2 \sqrt{3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - x =  - x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Now you can square both sides of the equation and then solve it.

Comment: But don't forget to exclude any spurious solutions you introduce by squaring both sides, and verify all solutions.